Error in adding an item to a list using + operator in python
I am getting unpredictable output with the following code
a = [1,2]
a = a+ '3'
print("a:",a)

this block of code gives an error
a = [1,2] 
a+='3'
print("a:",a)

this gives [1,2,'3']
Can anyone help me in figuring out what is wrong?

'3' is a string. Use a+=[3]

Your confusion is understandable, this situation is because fundamentally the +=  and + operators are not equivalent in function. This python discussion helps clarify the differences and reasons.
